# Python: When attempting to build dict by iterating through list of items, I end up adding all of the list items to every object in my JSON dict

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I've been banging my head against the wall for a while now, and I feel like there HAS to be a simple solution to this issue. Basically, I am iterating through a list of objects that I pulled from a DB (massiveList). I am hoping to build out a dict to use as JSON for reporting. However, when I try this, I end up adding *every item* from massiveList to each item's list in my resulting dict. I am distinctly creating a key out of values from the DB records so that I will only add the appropriate items to each item's list in the final dict.

For example, if there's 600 items in massiveList and I'm trying to sort them out into A items, B items, and C items, instead of getting len(A) + len(B) + len(C) = 600, I'm getting 600 items added to A, B, and C.

```
def addItemsToFinalDict():
    finalDict = {}
    newItemDict = {
        "list1": [],
        "list2": [],
        "key": 0
    }

    for x in massiveList:
        val1 = x[val1]
        val2 = x[val2]

        dictKey = (val1, val2)

        if dictKey not in finalDict:
            finalDict[dictKey] = newItemDict

        if x["test"] == True:
            finalDict[dictKey]["list1"].append(x)
        else:
            finalDict[dictKey]["list2"].append(x)

    return finalDict
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `finalDict[dictKey] = newItemDict` doesn't mean "set this entry value to a new dict copied from this template dict". It means "set this entry value to *this particular dict object* that I'm aliasing through all the other values too".

Comment: Python almost never implicitly copies objects. It's not like C++.

Comment: Ohhhh so it will just make all the values the same because it's using the exact same object?

Comment: Well that solved it for me! I copied the contents of that dict instead of using the object and it worked! So in this case, how CAN I use the contents of the dict as a template to clean up my code?

Comment: Instead of that kind of `template = <some expression> ... otherthing = template` pattern, it's usually better to directly write `otherthing = <some expression>` in Python. `copy.deepcopy` is a thing that exists, but it's slow and bug-prone, nothing like C++ copy construction or copy assignment.

Comment: So basically, just change ```finalDict[dictKey] = newItemDict``` to ```finalDict[dictKey] = newItemDict = { "list1": [], "list2": [], "key": 0 } ``` and there's not necessarily a better way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [user2357112 supports Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica), I learned that Python does NOT implicitly copy objects in this case, and that I was effectively reusing the same object over and over, leading over to all of my items having all the items from the original list. Changed it to this and it works:

```
def addItemsToFinalDict():
    finalDict = {}

    for x in massiveList:
        val1 = x[val1]
        val2 = x[val2]

        dictKey = (val1, val2)

        if dictKey not in finalDict:
            finalDict[dictKey] = {
                                  "list1": [],
                                  "list2": [],
                                  "key": 0
                                 }

        if x["test"] == True:
            finalDict[dictKey]["list1"].append(x)
        else:
            finalDict[dictKey]["list2"].append(x)

    return finalDict
```